# Multiple .ts (TypeScript) files shown in debug mode?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, typescript, visual-studio-2015

Whenever I run my ASP.NET Web forms project, I am observing that the .js file contain multiple instance of .ts (typescript) files. Please see the image below,

[image]

Has anyone noticed this behavior in their projects?

How do I fix this issue? Am I missing any setting in my project?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: I don't think anyone will be able to help you unless they had the same issue earlier. At least share a bit about your project structure.

Comment: Do all the files have the same content?